# Replace field in primary list if match found in secondary list

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I have a list containing roughly a couple thousand lines, each line containing either 4 or 5 fields.  I also have a second list, containing several lines, only 1 field.  Both list will be stored in a variable.

First List:

```
item_1 something something value something
item_2 something something value 
item_3 something something value something
item_4 something something value something
... 
item_2155 something something value 
item_2156 something something value something
```

Second List:

```
item_3
item_2155
```

Desired End Result:

```
item_1 something something value something
item_2 something something value 
item_3 something something new_value something
item_4 something something value something
...
item_2155 something something new_value 
item_2156 something something value something
```

I tried using sed in a while loop.  It sort of works, but this method keeps appending the list to itself each time it loops.  I also feel that awk may be a better solution for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

MYHUGELIST=$(command)
MYSHORTLIST=$(command)

while read -r line ; do
  sed "/^$line /s/1of3-possible-matches/newvalue/;/^$line /s/2of3-possible-matches/newvalue/;/^$line /s/3of3-possible-matches/newvalue/" <<< "$MYHUGELIST"
done <<< "$MYSHORTLIST"
```

Comment: Where is `new_value` in the expected output coming from? It's not present in either list or anywhere else in your sample input. Why do you want to use variables to hold your lists instead of files?

Comment: ```new_value``` isn't a variable, sed is replacing the existing ```value``` with a fixed value when a match is found.  In my attempted script, if there is a match in the 1st field of each list, then the 4th field will be replaced with the new value in the larger list. Each list can change at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you consider a solution using `awk` and not `sed`?  If yes,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' shortlistOneString < shortlist.txt

awk -v oldv=value -v newv=new_value -v s="$shortlistOneString" \
'BEGIN {n=split(s,a,"\n")} { \
found=0; \
for (i=1; ! found && i<=n; ++i) { \
  if (a[i] == $1) { \
    for (j=2; j<= NF; ++j) { \
      if ($j == oldv) { \
        $j = newv; found=1; break }}}}; \
print}' longlist.txt
```

#### Notes

- We read the entire `shortlist.txt`, newlines and all, into shell variable `shortlistOneString`.
- In `BEGIN` block, we split value of `"$shortlistOneString"` into an array we called `a`; this array has `n` elements, and we can access *i* th element with `a[i]`.  This block gets executed only once, before `awk` starts on the input proper.
- On its own, `awk` parses every line into a special reserved array; for any input line, this array has `NF` elements, and we can access *j* th element with `$j`; and can even overwrite those elements.
- For each line, `awk` will execute statements in the second block (whose first statement is `found=0` and last statement is `print`).
- If the *j* th field equals `oldv`, we overwrite that field with `newv` , and stop looking.  Because `awk` doesn't have multi-level `break` that Bash (for example) does, we make do with an auxiliary variable called `found`, which we reset to `0` for each line.
- Whether we overwrote a field or not, we `print` each line.
- This solution is more general than what you asked for.  You could tighten it up by only checking each line's *last field* `$(NF)` and *next-to-last field* `$(NF-1)`; you could even hardcode the field positions, as `$5` and `$4` respectively.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm only familiar with the basics of ```awk``` and ```sed```.  Your explanation helped me figure out how modify it to my needs and hopefully adapt it for future purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to emit an awk script

```
cmd1 | awk "$(cmd2 | sed -e 's:.*:/^& /{\$4=\"new_value\"}:')1"
```

where

- `cmd1` produces `$MYHUGELIST`
- `cmd2` produces `$MYSHORTLIST`
- each line in `$MYSHORTLIST` becomes `/^item_N /{$4="new_value"}`
- a final `1` in the awk script causes current line to print
- `$` and `"` characters are escaped as needed

Or, sed-only,

```
cmd1 | sed -e "$(cmd2 | sed -e 's:.*:/^& /s/[^ ][^ ]*/new_value/4:')"
```

where the `4` flag in the `s` command selects the 4th field.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your sed-only method and it works.  Is it possible with that method to append something to the old value?  Normally something like ```cmd | sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/\t&/4'``` would normally append a tab to the 4th field, but in your example it appends the match instead.

Comment: Yes, use a capture: `s/\([^ ][^ ]*\)/\1_was/4` replaces the 4th field with its old value appended `_was`; don't forget to escape the backslashes in this case since they're inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: Simpler: just use `s/[^ ][^ ]*/\&_was/4` so `&` isn't changed by the outer script.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one simple call to awk, no loops, pipes, or other commands are necessary.

If your data is in files:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{$4="new_value"} 1' secondFile firstFile
item_1 something something value something
item_2 something something value
item_3 something something new_value something
item_4 something something value something
...
item_2155 something something new_value
item_2156 something something value something
```

or if your data is in variables:

```
$ awk -v sec="$second" '
    BEGIN{split(sec,tmp); for (i in tmp) a[tmp[i]]}
    $1 in a{$4="new_value"} 1
' <<<"$first"
item_1 something something value something
item_2 something something value
item_3 something something new_value something
item_4 something something value something
...
item_2155 something something new_value
item_2156 something something value something
```

Comment: Thank you.  These methods worked for me as well.